# Is an Action-based Observer not recommended?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

For those of us who are new to the great power of `IObserver<T>` and `IObservable<T>`, we need to remember that these two interfaces are part of the core of .NET (literally in `mscorlib`). This is totally different from the [Reactive Extensions NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rx-Main/), which can be sadly dismissed as “non-standard.” For pathetic political reasons, I am motivated to confine Rx to *one* Visual Studio project. This effectively forces me to think up stuff like this:

```
public class CommunicatorObserver : IObserver<CommunicatorResult>
{
    public CommunicatorObserver(Action<CommunicatorResult> actionForObservableNext)
    {
        this.SetActions(actionForObservableNext, null, null);
    }

    public CommunicatorObserver(Action<CommunicatorResult> actionForObservableNext, Action<Exception> actionForObservableError)
    {
        this.SetActions(actionForObservableNext, actionForObservableError, null);
    }

    public CommunicatorObserver(Action<CommunicatorResult> actionForObservableNext, Action<Exception> actionForObservableError, Action actionForObservableCompleted)
    {
        this.SetActions(actionForObservableNext, actionForObservableError, actionForObservableCompleted);
    }

    public void OnCompleted()
    {
        if (this._actionForObservableCompleted != null) this._actionForObservableCompleted.Invoke();
    }

    public void OnError(Exception error)
    {
        if (this._actionForObservableError != null) this._actionForObservableError.Invoke(error);
    }

    public void OnNext(CommunicatorResult value)
    {
        if (this._actionForObservableNext != null) this._actionForObservableNext.Invoke(value);
    }

    public virtual void Subscribe(IObservable<CommunicatorResult> provider)
    {
        if (provider == null) return;
        this._unsubscriber = provider.Subscribe(this);
    }

    public virtual void Unsubscribe()
    {
        if (this._unsubscriber != null) this._unsubscriber.Dispose();
    }

    void SetActions(Action<CommunicatorResult> actionForObservableNext, Action<Exception> actionForObservableError, Action actionForObservableCompleted)
    {
        this._actionForObservableCompleted = actionForObservableCompleted;
        this._actionForObservableError = actionForObservableError;
        this._actionForObservableNext = actionForObservableNext;
    }

    Action _actionForObservableCompleted;
    Action<Exception> _actionForObservableError;
    Action<CommunicatorResult> _actionForObservableNext;

    IDisposable _unsubscriber;
}
```

My intent is to write my own, general-purpose-but-domain-specific Observer and avoid using the Rx `.Subscribe()` extension throughout my solution. Are there any pitfalls here? Is this the wrong way to go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, this is a very naive idea.

Rx is much more than just just the implementation you have there (and it appears broken already with the UnSubscribe concept you have).

Will your implementation cater for

- Serialization guarantees
- a Concurrency model that has been deeply thought through
- a concurrency model that can be unit tested deterministicly and at great spped
- Cancellation as a first class citizen for both subscriptions and concurrent/scheduled work
- The piles of operators that make Rx useful beyond a primitive event model.
- The man decades of in the field testing the Rx.NET has been put through
- The thousands of Unit tests already in the Rx code base.
- Community support when things get more complex than you have initially considered

As per James' advice. Step back and walk away. To go down the path of trying to implement IObservable and IObserver is fool hardy and will cost you in the long run. If your politics dictate that you need to do this, I would look for a new role too.

Comment: is there a more robust implementation that is separate from Rx---for any reason?

Comment: Not that I know of (and I cant imagine why there would be). If there was, it seems by the politics in your way, you wouldn't be able to use it anyway. If it helps your cause, Rx has been through a beta lifecycle 2009-2010 a v1 and go live cycle 2010-2012 and now is in v2 since 2012. Microsoft produced all of these .NET versions, and while it is "Open Source", it is not a free for all. When a pull-request is made, it takes months of verification from Microsoft to be accepted. You can take as much or as little as you want via nuget.

Comment: To further help your cause, it is used in at least 6 of the major investment banks (that I know of!). The primary reason Rx was not put in the BCL was so that it could evolve at a much higher cadence than the BCL. The BCL has only had 4 releases since IObservable<T> was introduced to .NET. In contrast Rx has had 18 Nuget releases, and we had been using numerous version of Rx prior to it being available on Nuget. This should be a strong argument for favouring a system like this, as if you did happen to find a bug or feature request you have a high chance of getting it in a nearby release.

Comment: I should be very clear that I am "allowed" to use Rx. I am unable to "force" others to use it. ...What I was looking for is `ObserverBase.cs` in [the source code](https://rx.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Rx.NET/Source/System.Reactive.Core/Reactive/ObserverBase.cs) of Rx.

Answer (score 3):

I've worked in many investment banks with draconian antiquated policies like this; Rx is open source though and even banks allowed me to pull in the source and compile it locally. Can't you even do that?

Rx addresses many non obvious issues that are only going to play out in certain scenarios, so it's hard to comment on your code; but if the source code idea doesn't fly, I can recommend you find a more reasonable employer!

Rx was developed by some very smart people at Microsoft and has been used actively in the field for several years now. You should definitely lobby harder if you can.

Comment: check out [this thread](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Three-Essential-Tips-for-Async/Lucian03-TipsForAsyncThreadsAndDatabinding) between some very passionate guy and Lucian Wischik (in the comments below) and we can see that TPL-biased folks (who are quite hip, not draconian at all) can come out against Rx.

Comment: I checked out the thread, but it seems to have a slightly different angle to me - more of a debate between two alternatives rather than wholesale advice not to use Rx because it isn't in the framework. In fact, *I* have recommended against Rx in that vein myself - see http://www.zerobugbuild.com/?p=337 :)

Comment: Interesting, I read that post as a white-wash win to the Rx guy. His comments are not very clear, but still I think he is right. The Task implementation is full of side effects (you poke this here and that over there does something). Oh and I dont think it supports cancellation! Just a thread left running for ever. And it is an async void method, so no error handling? TPL is pretty sweet, this is just not a good example of Task vs Rx. They are both good at different things. Sometimes there is some overlap too, which is cool.